# rbenv: how may I create a private bundle for an application?

Tags: ruby, rvm, rbenv, rbenv-gemset

I've never used **rbenv**, but now I need to know something about it and Google failed me.

When I'm using **rvm** and I want to create a private bundle for an application (say myapp), with Ruby 2.3.1, for instance, I just issue the command

```
rvm use ruby-2.3.1@myapp --ruby-version --create
```

This will create two files in the application root directory: **.ruby-version** and **.ruby-gemset**, as well as create the directory for the gems under **/home/username/.rvm/**.

What I would like to know is: **How may I achieve the same with rbenv?**

Comment: what do you mean a private bundle. To rely strictly on the gems in a Gemfile you just run bundle exec. rvm use just sets a ruby version in the current shell

Comment: A private bundle, @engineersmnky, means a directory to the gems of that specific application. Usually applications use a common bundle, i.e., a single directory for all applications. With this `rvm use ruby-2.3.1@myapp --ruby-version --create` I mentioned, I say to rvm to use a specific directory to that application.

Comment: ``rvm`` and ``rbenv`` are incompatible and should not be installed on the same system.

Comment: I know that, @zhon. And this is the reason why I'm asking here. If it were not by this, I'd have just installed rbenv and found it out by myself.

Comment: @engineersmnky Take a look at this, please: http://rubyofftherails.blogspot.com/2016/02/different-bundles-for-different.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a while since this was posted, but answering it in case others have the same question.

Brief answer: Use [bundler](https://bundler.io/) or [rbenv-gemset](https://github.com/jf/rbenv-gemset) plugin

Sharing more context on the general best practice:

> rbenv is used only to pick ruby versions by setting an environment
>   variable

Typically, it is used along with bundler and ruby-build. *Bundler is an alternative to rvm's gemsets and manages gems*. ruby-build plugin helps in installing different versions of rubies and automating it.